# Freezing headers in SSRS report while scrolling works only in IE

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an **SSRS report**. To *freeze the header row*, I went to Advanced mode in grouping section and set the **FixedData** property to True. This solved the issue, but it works in *Internet Explorer only*, not in Chrome and FireFox. Is it an issue with ReportBuilder or issue with the browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSRS support for non-Microsoft browsers is somewhat limited.

According to the MSDN site detailing browser support for SSRS 2008 R2:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.105).aspx

"Not all report functionality is supported by all browsers."  With this in mind, when asked to develop a reporting, I ensure my customer is aware that the reports may have limited functionality on other browsers.

It should also be noted that if developing PowerView reports for Sharepoint with SQL Server 2012, the browser plug-in Silverlight is required.  Silverlight is not available for iOS devices (iPhone, iPad).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the browser. A lot of features don't work in non-IE browsers like; SSRS parameter datepicker. You'll have to implement custom .nET code in non -IE browsers for this feature to work.

Comment: thnx mate. It would be great if u also provide link of some tutorial or something where I can get some idea for that custom code.

Comment: The only way to achieve this would be by writing a custom renderer.  This is a minefield as not all APIs are documented.  Furthermore, this would require a tremendous effort - there is no quick fix.  There is very little information out there on custom rendering.  If you require full cross-browser support, I recommend using a third-party renderer or different product.